# Nemo won't show basic information about file when it was accessed or modified

Tags: xubuntu, nemo

I am using Xubuntu, but I replace thunar with nemo, because nemo have more function like searchbox and open as root. But there is an issue on nemo. When i try to check info of file by`right-click > properties`. Basic info won't show the info about when last time that file **accessed or modified**.
It just showed :

> Accessed : Unknown
>
> Modified : Unknown

I try it again using thunar, it does show that info. It shows the time when I access and Modify it.

What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

I had the [same problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2CKk.png).

From the menu select *EDIT > PREFERENCES* then *DISPLAY*

[image]

Change the date format to: YESTERDAY

Then the date will show.